# OpenGL 1.x Displaying GL_QUADS with texture works, solid colour doesn't

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

First, my OpenGL Information (I grabbed this at run time):

> OpenGL version=4.0.10243 Compatibility Profile Context, vendor=ATI
>   Technologies Inc., renderer=AMD Radeon HD 6650M

So I'm working on a gui/hud rendering system for a few projects I'm working on, and I've ran into an interesting problem.  I can display textured GL_QUADS without an problem using the following code:

```
this->m_buffer->openglBindTexture();

SDL::Rect tc( this->m_buffer->getOpenGLTextureCoords() );           

glBegin( GL_QUADS );

    glColor4fv( (SDL::Color("white")).toGLColor4vf( 1.0 ) );
    glTexCoord2f( tc.topleft().x, tc.topleft().y );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().bottomleft().x, this->boundary().bottomleft().y, this->m_z );

    glTexCoord2f( tc.topright().x, tc.topright().y );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().bottomright().x, this->boundary().bottomright().y, this->m_z );

    glTexCoord2f( tc.bottomright().x, tc.bottomright().y );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().topright().x, this->boundary().topright().y, this->m_z );

    glTexCoord2f( tc.bottomleft().x, tc.bottomleft().y );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().topleft().x, this->boundary().topleft().y, this->m_z );

glEnd();
```

Some of that uses my own wrapper code around SDL+OpenGL.  Here is my binding code, just in case someone catches a quirk with it:

```
void Surface::openglBindTexture( void )
{
    int glerror = 0;
    if( !this->m_hastexture ) {
        int bpp;
        Uint32 Rmask, Gmask, Bmask, Amask;
        SDL_PixelFormatEnumToMasks(
            SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888, &bpp,
            &Rmask, &Gmask, &Bmask, &Amask
        );

        int glw = this->w_pow2();
        int glh = this->h_pow2();

        /* Create surface that will hold pixels passed into OpenGL. */
        SDL_Surface *img_rgba8888 = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,
            glw, glh, bpp,
            Rmask, Gmask, Bmask, Amask
        );

        SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod( this->m_surface, 0xFF );
        SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode( this->m_surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE );

        SDL_BlitSurface( this->m_surface, NULL, img_rgba8888, NULL );

        glGenTextures( 1, &this->m_texture );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->m_texture );
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glw, glh, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_rgba8888->pixels );
        glerror = GLException::glError(); if( glerror != 0 ) throw new GLException( "Surface::openglBindTexture::glTexImage2D", glerror, __FILE__, __LINE__ );

SDL_FreeSurface(img_rgba8888);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // Linear Filtering
        glerror = GLException::glError();
        if( glerror != 0 ) throw new GLException( "Surface::openglBindTexture::Importing raw texture", glerror, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
        this->m_hastexture = true;
    }
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->m_texture );
}
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use to display a simple coloured quad in opengl:

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().topleft().x, this->boundary().topleft().y, this->m_z );
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().topright().x, this->boundary().topright().y, this->m_z );
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().bottomright().x, this->boundary().bottomright().y, this->m_z );
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glVertex3f( this->boundary().bottomleft().x, this->boundary().bottomleft().y, this->m_z );
glEnd();
```

This does not draw anything.  I'm completely stumped, as I can see all of my textured quads without an issue.

**Edit**: I should note that I did some sanity checks and the boundary coordinates are all correct and visible.

**Edit 2**: Looks like when I don't do any textured quads, it works.  Does anyone see any part in the binding function that may break it?

Comment: Where do you set your texture environment (glTexEnv) stuff? Where do you activate and deactivate texturing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I just needed to add some logic for enabling and disabling GL_TEXTURE_2D each time I need it, rather than just keeping it bound in the opengl state business.

Comment: I'd have suggested just this.